# IOS 11 only: Navigation bar label off on top

Tags: ios, xcode9, swift4

IOS 11 is causing the main label to move a little bit from the top rather than keeping to the top. The problem only occurs on IOS 11. With different IOS everything looks ok.

Code sample with a setting header:

```
    private func setHeader(agentName: String = "", isTyping: Bool = false) -> Void {
    if (agentName.isEmpty) {
        self.containerViewController?.navigationItem.titleView = nil
    } else {
        let headerView: UIView = {
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 44)
            let uiview = UIView(frame: rect)

            return uiview
        }()


        let headerLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 20))
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return label
        }()

        let subheaderLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 12))
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = self.title
            return label
        }()


        headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
        headerView.addSubview(subheaderLabel)

        let viewsDictionary = ["header": headerLabel, "subheader": subheaderLabel]
        headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[header]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
        headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[subheader]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
        headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[header(20)]-[subheader]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

        self.containerViewController?.navigationItem.titleView = headerView

    }
}
```

[image: Label off]

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with iOS 11, views add to toolbars are now laid out using auto layout. You should add sizing constraints on your `headerView`. For example:

```
headerView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(320.0).isActive = true
headerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(44.0).isActive = true
```

Otherwise, auto layout will use the intrinsic content size of your header view which is likely not what you expect.

For more information see the WWDC 2017 session [Updating your app for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/).

Answer (score 0):

@beyowulf said that you have to add sizing constraints. I think in your case adding `height constraint` is okay :

```
headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.0).isActive = true
```